# Does the MVEL Null-Safe operator work on methods?

Tags: mvel

I have a question regarding the MVEL null-safe (`?`) operator.

Say I have the following Java class:

```
public class Traveler {

    private Set<String> visitedCountries;

    public Set<String> getVisitedCountries() {
        return visitedCountries;
    }
}
```

If I have an MVEL expression like this:

```
traveler.visitedCountries.contains("France")
```

I get a `NullPointerException` if the `visitedCountries` field is null.  To get around this, I can use the null-safe operator:

```
traveler.?visitedCountries.contains("France")
```

If `visitedCountries` is null, this expression evaluates to null instead of throwing the NPE.

My question is this: does the null-safe operator work on method invocations?  For example:

```
traveler.getVisitedCountries().contains("France")
```

will throw a `NullPointerException` if `getVisitedCountries()` returns null.

But what happens if I put in the null-safe operator?  What will the following do if the field `visitedCountries` is null?

```
traveler.?getVisitedCountries().contains("France")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the expression

```
traveler.?getVisitedCountries().contains("France")
```

does observe the null-safe operator.  It would evaluate to null here.  Unit test:

```
@Test
public void testMVELNullSafeOnMethod() throws Exception {
    Traveler traveler = new Traveler();
    // traveler visitedCountries field is null
    String expression = "traveler.?getVisitedCountries().contains(\"France\")";
    Serializable exp = MVEL.compileExpression(expression);
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("traveler", traveler);
    Boolean response = (Boolean) MVEL.executeExpression(exp, map);
    assertNull(response);
}
```